# Find the latest forms updated by contributors in gravityview

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I need to find the forms that have been modified in GravityView and also the forms that have not been updated by date. How can I do this?

I need to find the forms that have been modified in GravityView and also the forms that have not been updated by date. How can I do this?